# Set Theory & Function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

I need help in a statement I'm trying to prove.
I've already proven the one side of the question but I'm struggling with the other one (I will include the proof I've done below).

The statement I need to prove is as follows:

Let there be $F: A \rightarrow B$ and we'll define $G: \mathscr P(B) \rightarrow \mathscr P(A)$ (where $\mathscr P$ is the power set of a set) such that:

for every $C \in \mathscr P(B)$, $G(C) = \{a \in A | F(a) \in C\}$.

Given that and that $G(C) \subseteq A$, prove that $F$ is onto $B$ $\iff$ $G$ is injective.

---

I've proven one part where $F$ is onto $B$ $\leftarrow$ $G$ is injective.

We assume that G is injective, and let's incorrectly assume that there exists  $y \in B$ such so that $y \notin dom(F)$.

$y \in B$ so $\{y\} \in \mathscr P(B)$.

$\{y\} \in \mathscr P(B)$ so $G(\{y\}) = \{a \in A | F(a) \in \{y\}\}$.

Only $y \in \{y\}$, and $y \notin dom(F)$  so theree exists no $a \in A$ such as that $F(a) \in \{y\}$ and so $G(\{y\})$ is undefined.

Contradiction!

---

I'll be happy if someone could help me prove the other side and check my proof. Thanks.

Comment: Confused about the definition of $G$ which maps subsets of $A$ to subsets of $B$. But you define $G(C)$ where $C$ is a subset of $B$.

Comment: Sorry, meant that $G$ maps subsets of $B$ to subsets of $A$. Fixed now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let assume that $F$ is surjective. We must prove that If $C_1\subset B, C_2 \subset B$ such that $C_1 \neq C_2$ then $G(C_1)\neq G(C_2) $.

The fact is that $\forall x \in C_1 $ and $\forall y \in C_2$ $\exists x_0 \in A $ and $\exists y_0 \in A$ such that $F(x_0)= x, \space F(y_0)=y$, ($F$ is surjective).

Now take $\beta \in C_1 $ but $\beta \notin C_2$ then $\exists \alpha \in A $ such that $ F(\alpha)=\beta$, and necessarily $\alpha \notin G(C_2)$ so $G(C_2)\neq G(C_1)$.

Comment: Thanks, but could you explain a bit why if $\beta \in C_1$ then $\beta \notin C_2$ ? an why is $\alpha \notin G(C_2)$ necessarily?

Comment: I said : "Take $\beta \in C_1,  \beta \notin C_2$", an element like it there exists because $C_1\neq C_2$.

Comment: Well, but what if $C_1 \subset C_2$? Still doesn't mean they are equal...